# Is it possible to create multiple custom validation message for @Valid argument exception?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, constraints, bean-validation

I want to create custom message for my custom validation annotation. If this validation failed, it throws MethodArgumentNotValidException. Because I put @Valid for the @RequestBody.

I create @ControllerAdvice to handle/ override MethodArgumentNotValidException message. I have this enum error class separately. So every error that throws this kind of exception will throws the same message as `Invalid Param`

My question is is it possible to exclude my custom validation message and throws different message instead? How to make this @MyCustomAnnotation throws different exception message? Not fall under MethodArgumentNotValidException message.

My custom validation interface

```java
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = myValidator.class)
@Target({FIELD, METHOD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CheckMyCode{
    String message() default "{my custom string message}";
    Class<?> [] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

My controller advice method to handle all MethodArgumentNotValidException exception

```java
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request){
        CustomClassError<Object> error = CustomClassError.failure(ErrCode.INVALID_PARAM);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` method in controller advice like (seems this is the use case you need ):

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()) {
        details.add(error.getDefaultMessage());
    }
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Validation Failed", details);
    return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Or otherwise in your controller class you could handle it by throwing a custom exception and then handling it separately in your controller advice (not for validation exception but for all other run time exceptions this approach is preferable for handling the exception):

```
@PostMapping("/addValidate")
public String submitForm(@Valid ValidatedData validatedData,
  BindingResult result, Model m) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
         List<FieldError> errors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors(); // provided only for your information
         for (FieldError error : errors ) {
             System.out.println (error.getObjectName() + " - " +error.getDefaultMessage());
          }
        throw new CustomExceptionClass("Your could assign the field error custom message here");
    }
    m.addAttribute("message", "Success"
      + validatedData.toString());
    return "Home";
}
```

and then in your controller advice class you could use this message passed to the exception like :

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage()); //just call the message method to get the message in the exception
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Server Error", details); //Custom error response class to return json response
    return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```